# Proof/disproof $M_1 \subset M_2, M_2 \subset M_1$ or $M_1 = M_2$ for $M_1 = \mathring{A} \cap \mathring{B} \text{ and } M_2= (A \mathring{\cap}B)$

Tags: general-topology, analysis, proof-writing

Given are the sets $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$

I want to know if $M_1 \subset M_2, M_2 \subset M_1$ or $M_1 = M_2$ can be proven/disproven for this case:

$$M_1 = \mathring{A} \cap \mathring{B} \text{ and } M_2= (A \mathring{\cap}B)$$

I think

$$\overline{A \cup B} = \overline{A} \cup \overline{B} \text{ and } \mathring{(A \cap B)} = \mathring{A} \cap \mathring{B}$$

,which is why I think that

$M_1 \subsetneq M_2$

$M_2 \subset M_1$

$M_1 \neq M_2$

Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closures commute with finite unions and interior with finite intersections. So $M_1=M_2$.

$A^\circ \cap B^\circ$ is open and $A ^\circ \cap B^\circ \subseteq A \cap B$ so $A^\circ \cap B^\circ \subseteq (A \cap B)^\circ$

and $(A \cap B)^\circ$ is open and $(A \cap B)^\circ \subseteq A \cap B \subseteq A$ and so $(A \cap B)^\circ \subseteq A^\circ$, and likewise for $B$: 
$(A \cap B)^\circ \subseteq B^\circ$ so $(A \cap B)^\circ \subseteq A^\circ \cap B^\circ$. Hence equality $M_1=M_2$.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "commute with finite unions". Can you elaborate please?

Comment: @JavaTeachMe2018 $\overline{A \cup B}=\overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$ is wat I meant.

Comment: What does the circle superscript mean? Does it mean interior?  I have sometimes used that notation to indicate $A^\circ = \{ v\in V\; |  <v, a>\; \leq 0 \mathrm{\ for\ all\ } a\in A \}$ where $V$ is an inner product space with inner product $<\cdot,\cdot>$ and $A\subset V$.

Comment: The circle subscript means interior. In other words, $$A^\circ = \bigcup_{U\subset A, U\text{open in X}} U$$where $X$ is any topological space (not just $\mathbb R^n$).